# Java HttpURLConnection обработка ответа зависание блокирующее чтение

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Отправляю запрос на сервер GET запрос с помощью HttpURLConnection, мне приходит ответ, иногда в GZIP, а иногда нет.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class GetResponse {


    private String getResponseFromGetRequest() {
        String requestString = "https://www";
        URL obj = null;
        try {
            obj = new URL(requestString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            log.log(Level.WARNING, "URL obj - ", e);
            return "";
        }
        HttpURLConnection con = null;

        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.log(Level.WARNING, "Open Connection - ", e);
            return "";
        }

        try {
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            log.log(Level.WARNING, "Set Request Method GET - ", e);
            return "";
        }
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

        String contentEncoding = con.getContentEncoding();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        if (contentEncoding !=null & contentEncoding.equals("gzip")){
            try {
                inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.log(Level.WARNING, "Wrong connection - ", e);
                return "";
            }
        } else {
            try {
                inputStream = con.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.log(Level.WARNING, "Wrong connection - ", e);
                return "";
            }
        }

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null & in.ready()) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.log(Level.WARNING, "InputLine - ", e);
            return "";
        }

        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.log(Level.WARNING, "Not close BufferedReader - ", e);
            return "";
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

Один раз в 100-200 запросов у меня зависает вся программа, ничего не происходит, ошибок никаких не выдает.

Посмотрел dupm dreads, он показывает:

```
"pool-55-thread-3" #630 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8dc4017000 nid=0x4db3 runnable [0x00007f8d53cfa000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
- locked <0x00000000fde85e18> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
- locked <0x00000000fde85e28> (a java.lang.Object)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
- locked <0x00000000fde85e98> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
- locked <0x00000000fde85e98> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2942)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContentEncoding(URLConnection.java:523)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentEncoding(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:410)
at GetResponse.getResponseFromGetRequest(GetResponse.java:68)
at ThreadsMarathon.call(ThreadsMarathon.java:17)
at ThreadsMarathon.call(ThreadsMarathon.java:7)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Иногда там фигурирует 68 строчка, а иногда 91, это в данном коде следующие строчки:

```
String contentEncoding = con.getContentEncoding();
```

или

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine() != null)) {
```

Поискав решение нашел информацию, что зависание происходит из-за readLine(), так как возможно в некоторых случаях сервер не присылает символ окончания. Добавил в условие in.ready(). Все равно проблема не ушла.

На счет почему зависание происходит на строчке String contentEncoding = con.getContentEncoding(); вообще ума не приложу, ведь если что-то не не так с con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection(); то выскочило бы сообщение.

Может я что-то не так делаю?
Каким образом можно избежать зависания?
Как распознать что в именно в этом ответе будет происходить зависание и просто пропустить его?
Возможно ли установить какой-то таймаут, что если этот метод выполняется больше секунды - просто пропустить его?

Comment: долго разбирался со строчкой - while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null & in.ready()); вы уверены что именно так нужно организовать проверку?

Comment: @webnet75 такая же проблема была - http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread1298564.html

Comment: while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null && in.ready()) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }

Comment: "вы уверены что именно так нужно организовать проверку?" - нет, к сожалению, не уверен.

Comment: @ermak0ff "такая же проблема была" - Вы ее как-то решили?

Comment: @s_klepcha - допустим проблема с циклом решится посредством while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null && in.ready()) { response.append(inputLine); } . Как бить с зависанием в определении енкодинга - String contentEncoding = con.getContentEncoding();?

Comment: я не претендовал на ответ

Comment: @webnet75 "Вы ее как-то решили?" поднял старый код, а там значится цикл - условно бесконечный(пока пользователь сам не отключится) и в нем уже крутится Integer.valueOf(reader.readLine()); 

без никаких проверок)))) в общем по всей видимости я не особо долго искал решение)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [async-http-client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client).